# Get outlook-activities in a WP7-app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, outlook

How can I fetch the calendar-activities from Outlook in my Silverlight WP7-app? I want to make my own Agenda-app to run on my Windows Phone 7 (Omnia 7).

**UPDATE**

If not directly from phone calendar to my app, what other options do I have?

In my phone I currently have Windows Live and Outlook calendars. Im guessing that new Windows Live activities I enter on the phone is synched to my online Live-account? Could I then get those through a custom WCF-service/XML-feed instead perhaps? And likewise with the Oulook-calendar. It should be synched with the Outlook-calendar on the SharePoint-server. Maybee I can get the calendar-events in a custom server-app and feed it to the phone through the local network instead. Any suggestions?

And is there any way to add more calendar-sources then Live and Outlook to the WP7-calendar? Is there any API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: "you can't do that".

The long answer is: "sorry you can't do that".

All kidding aside, currently the API doesn't expose any method of accessing the user's calendar.  Rightly or wrongly they do this for security reasons.